# Python - Merge lists in a row from a list

Tags: python, list

I want to transform the `dataset` list, where the row is composed of different lists, to the `newDataset` list, where each row consists of one list composed of every elements of the different lists of `dataset` list.

```
dataset = [
[[2,3,1],[1,2,9],[1,3,8]],
[[1,4,1],[1,2,10],[9,3,1]],
[[1,4,0],[1,4,9],[2,5,8]],
]

newDataset = [
[2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 9, 1, 3, 8],
[1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 10, 9, 3, 1],
[1, 4, 0, 1, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8]
]
```

I have come up with the following line of code:

```
from itertools import chain
newDataset = [list(chain(*x)) for x in dataset]
```

But, I suppose there is a more pythonic way?

Another related question:
How could I generate `newDataset2`, where each row consists of the first element of the different lists of a row?

```
newDataset2 = [
[2,1,1],
[1,1,9],
[1,1,2],
]
```

Comment: Your solution is fine... Only recommendation is to use variable_names_with_underscores instead of CamelCase.

Comment: The second one is easy: `newDataset2 = [lists[0] for lists in dataset]`

Comment: @jamylak thanks for the tipp. My java habits kicked in. Started programming in Python a month ago. Really like what I see so far.

Comment: @phg This would take the first list of every row but not as intended the first element of each list of each row.

Comment: Yeah, right. I misunderstood that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
itertools.chain(*x)
```

is better expressed as

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)
```

but it is otherwise fine.

Also,

```
>>> [[x[0] for x in y] for y in dataset]
[[2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 9], [1, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Would you say `chain.from_iterable` is the better way of doing it? I've heard from others and it's my opinion that the long name makes it annoying to use unless performance is an issue.

Comment: @jamylak that looks to me more readable though. but you are right this's definitely shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
np.array(dataset).reshape(3,9)
```

returns

```
array([[ 2,  3,  1,  1,  2,  9,  1,  3,  8],
       [ 1,  4,  1,  1,  2, 10,  9,  3,  1],
       [ 1,  4,  0,  1,  4,  9,  2,  5,  8]])
```

the second one:

```
np.array(dataset)[:,:,0]
```

returns

```
array([[2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 9],
       [1, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. Thanks for the tipp as I am also dwelving into numpy.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset = [
[[2,3,1],[1,2,9],[1,3,8]],
[[1,4,1],[1,2,10],[9,3,1]],
[[1,4,0],[1,4,9],[2,5,8]],
]


print [[cell[0] for cell in row] for row in dataset]
```